# "stable_sort()ing" a STL <list> in C++

Tags: c++, list, stl, stable-sort

I think the question title is clear enough: is is possible to stable_sort() a std::list in C++? Or do I have to convert it to a std::vector?

I'm asking because I tried a simple example and it seems to require RandomAccessIterators, which a linked list doesn't have. So, **how do I stable sort a std::list()**?

**EDIT:** sample code that gives me an error:

```
#include <list>
#include <algorithm>
// ...
list<int> the_list;
stable_sort(the_list.begin(), the_list.end());
```

g++ gives me around 30 lines of errors (too long to paste), with some of them referring to RandomAccessIterators (and something called _merge_sort_loop). It's a little weird, since I've seen some merge sort implementations for linked lists and they are pretty much 'sequential'.

Comment: This is way insufficient information.  Reduce your problem to a fairly short piece of code, and post it.  Inform us what compiler (and, if necessary, what library), and what the actual error message is.  At that point, we can likely be useful.  Right now, any answer would be mere speculation.

Comment: This information is sufficient enough to give a correct answer (which is already given below by Nathan). Compiler and library can be presumed to be fully ISO C++ comliant unless otherwise specified, in which case it is entirely unambiguous.

Comment: The information is sufficient now, and I commend Rafael Almeida's efficiency in getting it there.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

std::list::sort is already stable.  From the standard, section 23.2.24: "Notes: Stable: the relative order of the equivalent elements is preserved."

Comment: That solves it then. But it's still strange that they have a stable_sort() algorithm.

Comment: stable_sort is for std::vector and other generic containers.

Comment: Bear in mind that the algorithms are not tied to containers, but there can be particular algorithm-container pairs that don't work together.